# Catastrophic Backtracking error validating email address

Tags: regex, email-validation

I need to find a regular expression that validates an email address in the simplest form and the email address should not exceed 250 characters. Here is what I came up with so far.

```
(?=.{1,250}$)(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}
```

The problem is this expression works for small email lengths sets. i.e. If I put 10 instead of 250 it will work. If I tested the above expression against large sample it will throw catastrophic backtracking exception. https://regex101.com/r/Dv2j2U/1. Can someone please help me solving this?

Comment: What do you think this does? `(.+){2,}` ? Just use `.{2,}`

Comment: haha i was faster :P

Comment: but cudos ... i never seen that "catastrophic backtracking" error before

Comment: @Fallenhero please add that as the answer..

Comment: @rawel  more info on catastrophic quantifiers [here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-explosive-quantifiers.html)

Comment: @Fallenhero i tried getting that error on regex101 but couldnt achieve it.. great job rawel

Comment: @AbdulHameed it's really not that difficult: https://regex101.com/r/CnI8Kw/1, the article you linked should give you a good insight how to achieve it.

Comment: It won't matter in most cases, but `(.+)@(.+)` is also prone to catastrophic backtracking. It would be safer to exclude the `@` character from one of the two groups, e.g. `([^@]+)@(.+)`.

Comment: If anyone wondering why this is downvoted, I guess it should be that "You should never come up with your own email validation regular expression" But you will never know when you will need one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `(.+){2,}` with `.{2,}`

Comment: Thanks @Fallenhero for the effort. I was finally able to come up with expression with your help. Working expression for me is (?=^.{1,250}$)(.+)@.{2,}\..{2,}